# Storing integers in an IBAction and passing them to another IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameter-passing, ibaction

I have a pause IBAction & a resume IBAction, both for buttons, but I have game points I collect over the duration of the game play. How can I store the different game points integer values in the pause IBAction & pass them to the resume IBAction method.

NOTE: The pause IBAction invalidates all the NSTIMERS, and the resume IBAction recreates them.

Comment: Store it as member variables of the class to which the IBActions are associated with. And read a beginner book on object oriented programming. Not being rude, but this is very very very very basic stuff and you won't get very far if you are having to ask this sort of stuff, so do yourself a favor and read some introductory tutorials.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to assist, I found a quick solution....but I'm sure there's a cleaner method:

In the vc.h:

```
NSMutableArray storeVariables;
```

In the vc.m

```
int a, b, c, d;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 a=0;
 b=0;
 c=0;
 d=0;
 storeVariables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender{
 a=3;
 b=4;
 c=5;
 d=6;
 [storeVariables addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
 [storeVariables addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:b]];
 [storeVariables addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c]];
 [storeVariables addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:d]];
 NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d, %d", storeVariables[0], storeVariables[1], storeVariables[2], storeVariables[3]);
}

-(IBAction)resumeButton:(id)sender{
 a = [storeVariables[0]];
 b = [storeVariables[1]]
 c = [storeVariables[2]]
 d = [storeVariables[3]]
 NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d, %d", a, b, c, d);
 storeVariables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, this really helped! The only major difference I made was not instantiating the Array twice, I just clear the old values! This helped a lot! I'll add my code for anyone that may need it in the future

Answer (score 1):

An IBAction is code. It can't store anything. You need to save your state somewhere like an instance variable of the object that implements the IBAction

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:
.h file-

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{

    NSMutableArray *savedScoreData;
    int PlayTimer;
    int timeMinute;
    int bonusPts;
    int enemykill;

}
```

.m file-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    PlayTimer = 0;
    timeMinute = 0;
    bonusPts = 0;
    timeMinute = 0;

    savedScoreData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"pause-before: %d, %d, %d,",PlayTimer,enemykill,bonusPts);
    [GameTimer invalidate]; //this constantly changes the PlayTimer & timeMinute variables
    [characterTimer invalidate]; 
    [enemyTimer invalidate]; //this constantly changes the enemyKill & bonusPts variables
    [_bonusImgHolder removeFromSuperview];
    if([_soundEnable isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
        [_player2 pause];
    }
    //NSLog(@"%tu",_player2.playing);
    _resumeButton.hidden = NO;
    _pauseButton.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"pause-after: %d, %d, %d,",PlayTimer,enemykill,bonusPts);
    //[sender num :PlayTimer];
    [savedScoreData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: PlayTimer]];
    [savedScoreData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: timeMinute]];
    [savedScoreData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: enemykill]];
    [savedScoreData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: bonusPts]];
    NSLog(@"%i", [savedScoreData[0] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [savedScoreData[1] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [savedScoreData[2] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [savedScoreData[3] intValue]);

}
- (IBAction)resumeButton:(int)pauseButton{
    NSLog(@"resume-before: %d, %d, %d,",PlayTimer,enemykill,bonusPts);
    PlayTimer = [savedScoreData[0] intValue];
    timeMinute = [savedScoreData[1] intValue];
    enemykill = [savedScoreData[2] intValue];
    bonusPts = [savedScoreData[3] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)enemykill);
    _resumeButton.hidden = YES;
    _pauseButton.hidden = NO;
    if([_soundEnable isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
        [_player2 play];
    }
    GameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(CollectPoints) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    characterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(Jumping) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    enemyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(enemyTravel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"resume-after: %d, %d, %d,",PlayTimer,enemykill,bonusPts);
    [savedScoreData removeAllObjects];
}
```